# Does "Zzz" (sleep) have the same meaning in Russian?

Tags: узус

Onomatopoetic "Zzz" is well known in languages that use the Latin alphabet. It means "sleep" in many languages. Is this also the case in Russian? Can "Ззз" be used to symbolize sleep?

Comment: `Can "Ззз" be used to symbolize sleep?` BTW. "з-зз" in Russian rather stands for mosquito's noise.

Answer (score 10):

No, it can not be used to symbolize sleep. Instead of it, we sometimes use "Хррр" to denote sleep.

Comment: Standalone "хррр" wouldn't be understood as symbol for sleeping. You would need a context, for example, picture

Comment: Ззз can be used to symbolize a fly or something like that (dragonfly, etc.).

Comment: Exactly. BTW, хрр comes from храп/храпеть (snoring/to snore).

Comment: *Хрр-пщщ, хрр-пщщ...*

Answer (score 0):

It's rather a well known english meaning by Russians, than the same meaning in Russian.
I.e., most Russians know this englshism, but it came from english-speaking inet and it doesn't, necessarily has any meaning in Russian.

Comment: I doubt even the majority of Russians who speaks English know this. I spotted this only when playing online games and initially thought it meant something else.